# Dynamic replacing and removing C code (using Perl)

Tags: regex, perl, dynamic, replace

I come to you with my question: what is the best way to replace/remove pieces of C code dynamically? I already did something in Perl using regular expressions and reading what to replace/remove from a configuration file but I can't make it dynamic.

Code:

```
#autoflush output so it will not interfere with calling application
local $| = 1;
##

#libraries
use warnings;
use strict;
use Switch;
use Cwd;
use File::Find;
##

#global variables
my @config;
my $file;
my $directory;
my $result;
##

if(@ARGV < 1)
{
    $directory = cwd();
}
else
{
    $directory = $ARGV[0];
}
$result = $directory . "\\result";

if(! -d $result)
{
    mkdir ($result);
}

open LOG, ">", $result . "\\log.log";

sub start
{
    my $configFile = $_[0];
    open CONFIG, $configFile;
    local $/;
    my $conf = <CONFIG>;
    close CONFIG;

    foreach my $line (split(/\n\*/, $conf))
    {
        if(index($line, "*") == 0)
        {
            $line = substr($line, 1);
        }
        setConfig($line);
    }
    processFiles();
}

sub setConfig
{
    my $line = $_[0];
    my $count = () = $line =~ /\s*==>\s*/;
    switch($count)
    {
        case 0
        {
            remove($line);
        }
        case 1
        {
            replace($line);
        }
    }
}

sub addSlashes
{
    $_[0] =~ s/([\.\\\/\+\*\?\[\^\]\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:\-])/\\$1/xg;
    if($_[1] == 1)
    {
        $_[0] =~ s/([\$])/\\$1/xg;
    }
    return;
}

sub remove
{
    my $line = $_[0];
    addSlashes($line, 1);
    $line =~ s/(\\\$){3}/\.\+/g;
    $config[@config][0] = qr/$line/;
    $config[@config - 1][1] = q("");
    $line = "\\(" . $line . "\\(";
    $config[@config - 1][2] = qr/$line/;
}

sub replace
{
    my $line = $_[0];
    my @split = split(/\s*==>\s*/, $line);
    my $original = $split[0];
    my $replace = $split[1];
    my $regex;
    addSlashes($original, 1);
    addSlashes($replace, 0);

    my $counter = 1;
    while($original =~ /\\\$([\d]{1,3})\\\$/g)
    {
        if($1 <= $counter && $1 > 0)
        {
            $counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            print "Invalid format\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    if($counter == 1)
    {
        $config[@config][0] = qr/$original/;
        $config[@config - 1][1] = q(") . $replace . q(");
        $original = "\\(" . $original . "\\(";
        $config[@config - 1][2] = qr/$original/;
        return;
    }

    while($replace =~ /\$([\d]{1,3})\$/g)
    {
        if($1 <= 0 && $1 >= $counter)
        {
            print "Invalid format\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    $original =~ s/\\\$\d{1,3}\\\$/\(\.\+\?\)/xg;
    $original =~ s/\?\)$/\)/xg;

    $replace =~ s/\$(\d{1,3})\$/\$$1/xg;

    $config[@config][0] = qr/$original/;
    $config[@config - 1][1] = q(") . $replace . q(");

    $original = "\\(" . $original . "\\(";
    $config[@config - 1][2] = qr/$original/;
}

sub processFiles
{
    my @files = grep { ! -d } glob "$directory\\*";
    foreach my $file (@files)
    {
        if($file =~ /\.(h|c)$/)
        {
            process($file);
        }
    }
}

sub process
{
    my $file = $_[0];
    open READ, $file;
    local $/;
    my $text = <READ>;
    close READ;
    print LOG "\n--> $file <--\n";
    for(my $i = 0; $i < @config; $i++)
    {
        my $original = $config[$i][0];
        my $replace = $config[$i][1];
        my $log = $config[$i][2];

        while($text =~ /$log/g)
        {
            print LOG $log . " ----> " . $1 . "\n";
        }

        $text =~ s/$original/$replace/eeg;
        print LOG "\n";
    }

    $file = $result . substr($file, rindex($file, "\\"));

    open WRITE, ">", $file;
    print WRITE $text;
    close WRITE;
}

start("qm2asil.cfg");

close LOG;
```

Configuration file content:

```
*static 
*GET_$1$() ==> $1$
*GET_$1$($2$) ==> $1$[$2$]
*SET_$1$($2$,$3$); ==> $1$[$2$] = $3$;
*SET_$1$($2$); ==> $1$ = $2$;
```

The idea is that there are already a few rules to replace/remove and they work but can exist more complex rules that I couldn't manage.

Example:

```
SET_VAR1((i),(u8)(((s32)(((s32)GET_VAR2 ((i))) != 0)) && ((s32)((u8)(((s32) (((s32)VAR3[i]) != 0)) ^ ((s32)(((s32) VAR4[i]) != 0)))))));
```

I want to remove SET function and make it an assignment to the variable (VAR1[i] = ...). This is one of many variations of things that need to be removed/replaced.

What do you advise me to do? Can I make it work using Perl and regex or I should reorientate to another method and/or programming language?

EDIT: I already create regexes based on the configuration file but I have problem matching unknown expressions (currently I use .+). The main idea is that I want to keep the configuration as simple I can.

[regexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK8LO.png)

Comment: Don't use [Switch](http://p3rl.org/Switch), it's dangerous. It's definitely doable in Perl, but whether *you* can make it depends on how well you know Perl.

Comment: I'm not an axpert in Perl. I did only a few scripts. Can you tell me what have you thinked of? Should I let regex and do it with substr-index?

Comment: I'd probably try with regexes - and I mean the plural.

Comment: regexes I tried too... my script's approach is that reads the configuration file and creates an array of regexes then for each file that needs to be processed applies regex substitution.

Comment: I would strongly recommend a State Machine for this task.  Multiple complex regexes are likely to produce nasty surprises, and are difficult to test in an exhaustive way.

Comment: I understand the concept of a state machine but how can I apply it to my problem?